# JSON search event names and list URL values

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I'm loading event listing as an JSON-File from an URL:

```
$file = file_get_contents('http://ecample.com/listing.php?'); 
$data = json_decode($file); 
?>
```

The direct output looks like this (more values and mor lines):

```
    [{"id":"1","name":"NAME_1","booking_url":"https://ecample.com/Event_ID65654","category_id":"195"},
    {"id":"2","name":"NAME_2","booking_url":"https://ecample.com/Event_ID65654","category_id":"195"},
    "id":"1","name":"NAME_1","booking_url":"https://ecample.com/Event_ID65654","category_id":"195"}]
```

I need to search for all entrys with the value "name":"NAME_1" and print out the value of "booking_url".

I tried different things like `array_seach()` etc. but did not work out.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Show us some examples of what you've tried.

Comment: I've tryed a lot of foreach stuff like 

this foreach ($data['name']['booking_url'] as $key=>$value){
 echo $value[1]." , ".$value[2]." , ".$value[3] . "<br>"; 
}

and a bunch of other stuff i already deleted...

Comment: The problem is I can't get access to the array in inside foreach :(

If I print_r $data it looks like this:
 `Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => NAME_1
            [booking_url] => http://ecample.com/listing.php
   [category_id] => 195
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
  (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => NAME_2
            [booking_url] => http://ecample.com/listing.php
   [category_id] => 195
        )
)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
<?php

    $file = file_get_contents('http://ecample.com/listing.php?'); 
    $data = json_decode($file, true);

    foreach ($data as $r)
    {
        if ($r['name'] == 'NAME_1')
        {
            echo $r['booking_url'];
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: THX but I already tryed this...  makes a blank screen :( 
If I print_r $data it looks like this
 `code` Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => NAME_1
            [booking_url] => http://ecample.com/listing.php
   [category_id] => 195
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
  (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => NAME_2
            [booking_url] => http://ecample.com/listing.php
   [category_id] => 195
        )
)

Answer (score 0):

The other option is to access your data in object context, thus:

```
<?php

    $file = file_get_contents('http://ecample.com/listing.php?'); 
    $data = json_decode($file);

    foreach ($data as $r)
    {
        if ($r->name == 'NAME_1')
        {
            echo $r->booking_url;
        }
    }

?>
```

Either one should work just as well.